# Handle the request param dynamically with Jackson library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a rest controller which has a GET request and the request param could be of any type which is more dynamic i would say. I would like to map the request param to an appropriate child class based on the data we get from user.
BaseRequest Class is `

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestA.class, name = "RequestA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestB.class, name = "RequestB")
})
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseRequest {
    private String error;
}
```

`RequestA class is`

```
@Data
@JsonTypeName("RequestA")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestA extends BaseRequest {
    private String token;
}
```

`

RequestB is `

```
@Data
@JsonTypeName("RequestB")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestB extends BaseRequest {
    private String id;
}
```

`

My controller is `

```
@GetMapping(value = "/request", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String request(BaseRequest request)
```

`

The request would look like
1)http://localhost:8080/request?token=abc&error=test
2)http://localhost:8080/request?id=abc
It doesnt seem working. I only get info for Base class at controller.

Comment: Request parameters are not JSON and do not use Jackson. You will need either a custom data binder or to use request mappings that include parameter listings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GET it won't use JSON, you could write

```
@GetMapping(value = "/request", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public String request(@RequestParam(required = false) String token,
 @RequestParam(required = false) String id, @RequestParam(required = false) String error) {
  //Initialize request A if token is not null else request B or add your custom control
}
```

if you need more params with different purposes you could create a custom object to be passed in a POST body and then, based on your needs, make the correct call.